# Audit adds a tag to a question automatically in a filtered review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just passed an audit in the queue filtered to see only Fortran. The question was about R and the system probably added the Fortran tag only for the audit. I naturally chose Edit to re-tag and therefore I passed. Does it make sense to have such audits as I did not actually review the quality of the content?

Comment: see the answer [over there at cross-site dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204645/165773): "...this completely serves the purpose of testing whether or not you're paying attention to what you click while reviewing" (IOW test is dumb but it manages to catch abusive reviewers, your pass verifies that you're okay)