# What kind of Audit is that?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10106143

That's painfully obviously a bad question, not specific, too broad, you could almost choose from a list on why you can close this without further notice.

How is it then a high quality post audit? I'm sorry but I wouldn't upvote this. In fact I can't think of anyone who would upvote this.

I failed audits before, justifiably so, and I mostly understood them (or at least partly). This one just boggled my mind.

Comment: I think it's a pretty specific, clear question though. It's reasonably well-written, the problem is clear, and there's only one valid answer. It's not that good an audit question though.

Comment: @CodeCaster Its not. There are no specifics, the entire thing has no real pointer to whats exactly is the problem, there are a variety of reasons why this issue could happen. Tbh its comical with how quick and clean SO is with closing too broad questions normally that this one would not only stay open but get upvoted.

Comment: _"there are a variety of reasons why this issue could happen"_ - sure, but in this case it's a very specific one. There's issues with IDEs just like this one all over SO (_"You need to run it as admin"_, _"You need to install Service Pack X"_, ...), and I don't know of any developer that wouldn't find that helpful information. I do agree that when looking sec at the question it isn't that useful, but the question and answer are useful for many. In general I also don't like questions where you have to know the (unspecified!) issue to be able to answer, but I wouldn't like to see this removed.

Comment: @CodeCaster I disagree. I find it too broad and have flagged it for closure as too broad and downvoted it. I hope it does get closed and not used as an Audit from here on out.

Comment: Is this a one time problem, or does this happen each time ios is updated. What it boils down to is RTFM, and RTFM questions are generally on topic if not duplicates/low quality. the increased upvotes is likely a good sign that this user wasn't the only one to have this problem, and that the question is being found, so.... i'd say leave it up. Your downvote will at least remove it from being eligible to be an audit.

Comment: Coming at it as someone who knows nothing about X-code, it's hard to tell if it's specific or not, because it doesn't say where the error is coming from or what they were trying to do when they got it. But maybe to people who use X-code, it's obvious where the error is coming from.

Comment: Given the comments you've received so far, I think you can say one thing for sure: it's nowhere near as painfully obvious as you think it is.

Comment: @hvd Maybe its my conformation bias, but strictly speaking, if I was presetned with this again, I would still flag it as unclear what you're asking and move on. I guess some disagreements don't melt through discussion.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

By all appearances, this question was fairly straightforward to folks with experience using Apple's dev tools. If that doesn't include you, then you probably should've *Skipped* instead of trying to close.

Just as there's nothing particularly subtle about the question, there's nothing particularly subtle about the audit based on it; you tried to close a question that you should've left open or skipped. Learn from the experience, and do better next time!

Comment: The OP might also consider using a filter for subjects they're familiar with. (This will, of course, have the [side effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277755/1394393) of making it easy to spot audits.)

Comment: @jpmc26 that's not a problem (easy to spot audits), the whole point it is to catch people who go through it with their eyes shut.

Comment: The actual problem is that the audit system keeps picking various border line cases for audit reviews. To have a trick question audit based on "muahaha, you can only review this if you know about tool x" isn't really encouraging more people to do reviews. Currently there are 933 low-quality reviews in the queue and SO keeps discouraging reviewers with all these dysfunctional audits. Personally, I pretty much stopped doing reviews solely because of the broken audit system.

Comment: How is that a "trick", @lundin? Are you in the habit of closing questions in topics you don't understand? If not, then you'd skip such "tricky" audits and all would be well... If so, then... The system works if you fail.

Comment: @Shog9 quite right. Closing or deleting valuable content is far worse than leaving crap content open and visible. People absolutely shouldn't be choosing to shut down or censor posts in areas they know nothing about because they superficially look like maybe they're unclear to somebody with no knowledge of the field; it's better that ten pieces of crap sit around on the site forever than that one post of value be closed or deleted. If reviewers want to risk destroying or blocking valuable content by acting recklessly in areas they don't understand, then let them suffer the consequences.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok so this particular review audit wasn't as broken as some. Still, the point is that we get many of these meta threads regarding such audits every week. Behind every thread there's a disgruntled reviewer. And at the same time, the low-quality review queue has exploded.

Comment: not sure if trolling @Mark

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier not trolling, utterly serious. Don't lose sight of what closing and deleting bad posts is *for*. That crap content merely exists in the universe doesn't make it harmful; it is only a problem insofar as it is "noisy" - it wastes time of answerers or Googlers, delaying or preventing them creating or finding good content. Closure and deletion are only useful insofar as they remove that noise or deter its creation. They don't need to wipe out much innocent content in the process before they harm answerers and Googlers worse than if closure and deletion didn't even exist.